# Booting stops at Loading initial ramdisk

Tags: linux, arch-linux, linux-kernel

I have installed Arch Linux on 40GB HDD on ga-g4mt-s2p1 Motherboard ( Intel Core 2 multi-core,2Gb  of Ram)

I have made 4 Partitions:

```
/boot 100Mib
Swap 4Gib
/ 20Gib
/home The rest of the disk
```

It runs well without any problems but when I try the hard on and older Motherboard p4p800-mx(Pentium 4,512 Mb of Ram)
the booting stops at:

> loading linux
>
> loading initial ramdisk

Edit:Before the Grub menu I have this message

> CMOS Settings Wrong
>   CMOS Date/Time Not Set
>   Press F1 to Run Setup
>   Press F2 to load default value and continue

Comment: this is a *lot* easier to trouble shoot without `grub`. you should uninstall it.

Comment: I couldn't find any way to unistall it 
I'm using Arch as full boot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by changing my version from x86_64 to i686

In the installation menu, there are two choices one for `x86_64` and one for `i686`. My problem was with `x86_64` but when I reinstalled it choosing `i686`, it worked fine.

The CMOS problem was solved by changing the CMOS battery.

Comment: please explain about the version

Comment: I solved it in a similar way, I chose the wrong architecture in VirtualBox (32 Bit, worked with 64 Bit)

Answer (score 7):

It probably moves on, actually, but you don't see anything because the kernel's messages are not enabled. This happens when the boot loader passes the option `quiet` to the kernel.

Please try booting your system again, but without that option. If you're using `grub` as the boot loader, this is done as follows:

- when you reach the grub menu, select the option that you would normally boot, and press the `e` button on your keyboard.
- you will now see a full-screen editor. Find the line that starts with `linux`. This line contains the kernel command line. Remove the option `quiet` from that line, and *nothing else*. (if you accidentally do remove something else, just hit `esc` and start over).
- Once you've made the above change, press `ctrl`+`x` to execute the script without saving it.

You should now get much more information about why things aren't booting.

Comment: Still the same sir nothing new happened but with a new statement above Booting a command list

Comment: I wonder if you don't have to remove also additional option `splash` from there, however the root case of my issue was solved by replacing GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="dis_ucode_ldr" in /etc/default/grub.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by choosing earlier kernel version from advanced options from grub menu and update to all packages fixed the issues.

Answer (score 1):

I get the 'loading initial ramdisk' message, too, using system encryption with LUKS and LVM. This happens for me on Debian (netinstall) as well as on Alpine Linux.

To get past this, enter the (correct) LUKS password and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This results in a regular boot.

Answer (score 0):

f12 -> recovery mode of linux distro -> there I chose upgrade packages, if it did not work as it seemed it did not find my internet connection. So I continued starting into recovery mode , there I run sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade, restarted and it worked.

Other way, In safe-mode or command line, edit /etc/default/grub and replace in the existing configuration line

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

with

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="dis_ucode_ldr"

the issue is either caused by restarting in a different display configuration that it was prior. Either previously having connected a display and starting without it, or not having and starting with it. It happens when having set up UEFI startup mode, and might be fixed by BIOS update.