# Stuck at "Loading initial ramdisk" after attempt to update the kernel

Tags: debian, kernel, syslog, intel, firmware

I have an Asus FX433N with an UHD 620 Intel graphics. The system has a dual-boot with windows 10 and debian stable, where both system works just fine. I was trying to use wine and the system complain that a video card was not detected. I follow the instructions described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420678/how-do-i-install-update-drivers-on-debian-9?noredirect=1&lq=1) to update the kernel:

- echo deb http://http.debian.net/debian stretch-backports main contrib non-free > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list
- apt update
- apt -t stretch-backports install linux-image-amd64
- apt install -t stretch-backports firmware-linux

After that, I reboot the system and get stuck on the boot. When I select the Debian system, it's get stuck on "Loading initial ramdisk" and no key works at all. Ctrl+D, or Ctrl+C or even REISUB combination.

I do a fast research and I have found [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1829620) where the bug is described in the same system. There it's described a workaround:

> WORKAROUND 1: disable intel microcode updates during boot
>   From this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/intel-microcode/+bug/1759920
>   1/ add the boot parameter: dis_ucode_ldr to /etc/default/grub
>   2/ update-grub

Thanks to that workaround I can boot the system, but it's running really slow. Entry to TTY1 to avoid use GUIS and see if there is any advice I can follow, the console give a lots of code where one line repeats over 22-23 seconds with the message from syslog

> watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#7 stuck for 22s!

I guess that is whats explains why the whole system gets really slow, because when I try to use commands, the system can not complete them.

I imagine that maybe I forgot to do the update-grub and then I try to run it from chroot with a LIVE CD. After that, it delete the Windows entry from grub and Debian still not working. Total disappointment.

I managed to run dpkg -l | grep firmware and I get:

```
amd64-microcode
firmware-amd-graphicslwifi
firmware-iwlwifi
firmware-linux
firmware-linux-free
firmware-linux-nonfree
firmware-misc-nonfree
fwupd-amd64-signed
intel-microcode
```

I'm newbie on Linux so I don't know what to do. How can I know what causes that soft lockup?

My system is:

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620
NVIDIA GeForce MX150 ( I have not worried to install nothing about this because I don't use the card on Debian)
```

Comment: maybe check related stuff - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/620355/176449

Answer (score 2):

The instructions you followed are for Debian 9, but the current stable release, which you’re running, is Debian 10. To upgrade your kernel to a newer version on Debian 10, you need to specify `buster` instead of `stretch`:

```
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list
echo deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/buster-backports.list
apt update
apt -t buster-backports install linux-image-amd64
apt install -t buster-backports firmware-linux
```

That should allow your system to boot properly again.

Comment: I try your solution (thanks, btw) with a chroot from a live cd and didn't work. It's possible run this from chroot, right?

Comment: It’s possible, but it depends on what you did exactly, especially for the Grub menu update.

Comment: I try with a different live cd and it works! Thanks!